# Login page AJAX redirect doesnt work

Tags: php, ajax

I use php with ajax.

```
<?php
/*
* Suppose, user has entered both correct login and password
* then server response is TO **REDIRECT** to profile page
* 
/
 header('location:/');
/*
* 
* print <<<HTML
<scrpit> window . location = '/profile.php';</script>
HTML;
* also doesnt work    
**/
?>
```

The problem is that it does redirect, but leaves part of authorization page, and the result = is mixed profile + auth page

Comment: So you're saying a form has been submitted using ajax, and you're trying to redirect the user with your PHP controller? Just pass back the redirect url in your callback and have js redirect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using AJAX, redirecting using `header()` will not work.

This is what will happen:

- Request is sent to your PHP page.
- You send back a redirect header with location.
- Browser fetches the redirected page.
- Contents of the redirected page is then passed to your XMLHttpRequest object.

What you need to do is:

- Determine if the request is ajax by checking to see if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` has the value of `xmlhttprequest`. Most JS libraries will send this.
- If it is not AJAX, redirect using `header('Location: /')`
- If it is AJAX, send back a JSON response with a location and status code for your javascript part to redirect, or `echo('location.replace("\")');`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AJAX call to the page as written above, using both `header()` and `JavaScript` to redirect won't work. You need to use javascript in order to redirect page. Sample codes:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Suppose, user has entered both correct login and password
     * then server response is TO **REDIRECT** to profile page
     */

    // define login is false by default
    $response = array();
    response['Success'] = false;

    // use if-condition to check if succeeded
    // then assign it to true like this
    response['Success'] = true;
    die( json_encode($response) );
?>

    // Javascript Code:

    // You must decode it first since it's json
    // Assuming that `theResponse` is the message callback
    var responseStr = JSON.parse( theResponse );
    if ( responseStr.Success ){
        location.href = 'profile.php';
    }else {
        // show some message
    }
```